# ESRI GDB Support in GDAL / ogr2ogr on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase, mac

How do you incorporate support for ESRI's fgdb format into GDAL / ogr2ogr on Mac OS X 10.8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, self, I'm glad you asked (hopefully you won't have to spend a whole day figuring this out next time).

### Steps

1. Download the [ESRI File Geodatabase API Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20130704110629/http://resources.arcgis.com:80/content/geodatabases/10.0/file-gdb-api) (requires account)
2. Move the resultant `FileGDB_API` folder to `/usr/local/`
3. Copy all the files from (or symlink for cleaner in/uninstall)

- `/usr/local/FileGDB_API/include/` ---> `/usr/local/include`
- `/usr/local/FileGDB_API/lib/` ---> `/usr/local/lib`

3. Run `brew install gdal --enable-unsupported`

- `brew` requires the invaluable [homebrew](https://brew.sh) package manager to be installed
- I personally had to add `--without-python` to avoid issues with python support (numpy install issues)

Now, you should be able to, for example, convert fgdb files to better, more open formats by running

```
/usr/local/bin/ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output_file.json input_file_gdb_folder
```

### Why You Have to Manually Add FGDB Support

Support for ESRI's fgdb format can't be built into GDAL by default as it is a non-open source library. However, it can be added. Hence, the machinations above.

#### Inspiration

I found a few, disparate articles that really helped me put this all together into a cohesive piece

- [OGR Vector Formats](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html)
- [ESRI File GeoDatabase FileGDB](https://gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html)
- [Installing GDAL/OGR with FileGDB support on OSX with Homebrew](https://blog.burhum.com/post/34851795066/installing-gdalogr-with-filegdb-support-on-osx)
- [Homebrew GDAL Formula (for install command options)](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/gdal.rb)

Comment: Having done this so many different ways, I would say that Homebrew is the way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

This did not work for me for OS X 10.11. Glad I found [this](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac):

The gist of it:

1. brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac
2. Download FileGDB API for http://appsforms.esri.com/products/download/#File_Geodatabase_API_1.3 and place it in Homebrew Cache Directory
3. brew install gdal-filegdb

Comment: Since Esri has released the fileGDB API under an Apache 2.0 license, it's no longer necessary to separately download the API source [from Esri](https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api) ). The current osgeo4mac bottle is called `osgeo-gdal-filegdb` (e.g. `brew install osgeo-gdal-filegdb`)