# Homebrew OGR with FGDB support on OSX 10.9

Tags: gdal, ogr, file-geodatabase, osx, homebrew

[This answer worked beautifully in 10.8](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43652/esri-gdb-support-in-gdal-ogr2ogr-on-mac-os-x-10-8), but isn't working immediately in 10.9.

The [link to download the FileGDB API](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/#File_Geodatabase_API_1.3) still works, but there are a bunch of options available I don't remember from before. Do we want the Mac version, or the Linux one? Version 1.2 or 1.3?

I've tried the Mac version 1.3 so far.

Answer (score 1):

I missed this thread and had much the same [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81783/file-geodatabase-api-on-osx-mavericks-via-brewed-gdal).

Mac version 1.3 still works for some purposes (data translation with ogr2ogr is all I've tested so far) if installed as a shared gdal plugin. @dakcarto maintains a homebrew formula for doing this:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/95958-OS-X-Mavericks

https://github.com/dakcarto/homebrew-osgeo4mac

Comment: Please note: you can load FileGDB directories into QGIS  (the ones I tested) using GDAL with the shared plugin built off of the FileGBD 1.3 lib, but due to the incompatibility of the C libs GDAL and FileGDB are compiled against, QGIS may crash on some operations, like accessing [the attribute table](https://github.com/dakcarto/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/8). I _highly recommend_ just using the plugin for converting your FileGBD data to another geospatial format, until ESRI updates the libs to work with 10.9, i.e. do not use the plugin to write to an existing FileGBD, or use Kyngchaos builds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to post the answer with the necessary linked documentation. I've put my solution on a public gist to overcome that.

In a nutshell, though, you need to install gcc-4.9 from homebrew, do a netcdf workaround (if you want netcdf support in gdal), rebuild one dependency (ldap) with gcc-4.9, then install gdal using a custom gdal formula that I have available as a separate gist, also using gcc-4/9. Finally, you need to redirect lib references to point to the gcc-4.9 supplied libs with install_name_tool.

The details are available **[here](https://gist.github.com/jctull/7403665)**.