# file geodatabase api on osx mavericks via brewed gdal

Tags: gdal, osx, file-geodatabase-api

I've got a new machine with a fresh install of OSX 10.9, and am having trouble getting esri's file geodatabase api to work correctly with my brewed gdal.

This is a known issue, noted here:
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/95958-OS-X-Mavericks

I've tried John Tull's noted [workaround](https://gist.github.com/jctull/7403665):

```
# install gcc
brew install --enable-cxx gcc49

# noted fgdb/gdal dependency:
brew install libdap --cc="gcc-4.9"

# gdal 
brew install gdal --enable-unsupported --with-postgresql -v --cc="gcc-4.9"

# this points the fgdb libraries at gcc4.9 somehow
install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9-20131103/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.9.0/libstdc++.dylib /usr/local/opt/FileGDB_API/lib/libFileGDBAPI.dylib
install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9-20131103/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.9.0/libstdc++.dylib /usr/local/opt/FileGDB_API/lib/libfgdbunixrtl.dylib
```

This helps - `ogr2info --formats` now shows `FileGDB` as a valid format.
However, running ogr2info on a valid filegdb gives this error:

```
ogrinfo(45386,0x7fff74779310) malloc: *** error for object 0x10b49dde0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I tried removing all of the gdal dependencies and letting homebrew reinstall them when calling `brew install gdal` with the `--c"gcc-49"` flag but that didn't change anything.

edit - I now see that this issue already has a thread here [Homebrew OGR with FGDB support on OSX 10.9](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75287/homebrew-ogr-with-fgdb-support-on-osx-10-9)

Comment: found the problem. I didn't check the install_name_tool arguments closely enough.

Comment: nope. Fixed the path but that didn't work. I don't understand well enough what the install_name_tool is doing to debug - presuming that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Question is answered well enough (by @dakcarto) for my purposes here:

https://github.com/dakcarto/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/8

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/95958-OS-X-Mavericks?p=355416#post355416

Installing the api as a shared gdal plugin seems to be the key.