# Importing .gdb database into PostGIS

Tags: file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to import a file database into PostGIS. Running ogrinfo on my database I get:

```
..$ ogrinfo BRP_Gewaspercelen_2009.gdb 

Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `BRP_Gewaspercelen_2009.gdb'
      using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.
1: BRP_gewaspercelen_2009_definitief (Multi Polygon)
```

So I guess I have the required driver to load the file. But ogr2ogr throws me this error:

```
 ..$ ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5433 dbname=crops
 user=postgres" BRP_Gewaspercelen_2009.gdb 
-overwrite -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES

FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `BRP_Gewaspercelen_2009.gdb' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> WAsP
  -> PCIDSK
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDump
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> XLS
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> PDF
  -> CartoDB
  -> SXF
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have space character in the file name and ogr2ogr believes that the name ends at that point. Double quotes around name might help. Otherwise I would rename and try again.

Comment: Thanks @user30184 but that doesn't seem to be the issue

Comment: Is the error different now? Message "Unable to open datasource `brpgewaspercelen' " means that ogr2ogr was searching for that shortened name.

Comment: @user30184 i went one level deep into the directory "brpgewaspercelen 2009" and referenced "BRP_Gewaspercelen_2009.gdb" direcrtly. and i got the same messae that it "Unable to open datasource ...". Btw, I'm trying the solution in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43652/esri-gdb-support-in-gdal-ogr2ogr-on-mac-os-x-10-8 and at least i don't get an error right away (i'm not sure if it's working yet ..). but strange that OpenFileGDB is there and it can even see file contents with ogrinfo -al but ogr2ogr doesn't ..

Comment: Add "--debug on" into your command and you may get more info.

Comment: You should not ***ever*** load data as superuser. Best practice calls for independent, minimally privileged logins for data management. Please [edit] the question to specfy the versions of all software in use.

Comment: your command seems to be the correct syntax. Maybe try putting -overwrite -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES at the beginning of the command

Comment: Did you cd to the gdb directory before running the conversion command?  If not, you may need to provide the entire file path to gdb.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like the version of gdal that you have supports .gdb files. Judging by the:

```
Unable to open datasource `BRP_Gewaspercelen_2009.gdb' with the following drivers.
```

it seems like it was able to read the right file but just doesn't support. Try this?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal20 libgeos-c1v5 postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.2 postgis
```

then to check the version run:

```
ogr2ogr --version
```

It should output something like

```
GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25
```

On a side note you probably need to upgrade your postgis to 2.2.